# Writing to texfile issue.(Python3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.5

Intro: I am using 2 for loops to iterate through a 10x10 board , this is done in order to save all the positions to a textfile. I am a beginner to this so that is why my code looks simplistic.

Issue: I need to print a new line in the textfile after each iteration of the first for loop. The actual saving part I have done.

Link to current and desired output: http://pastebin.com/Un12u5L8

Code:

```
def SaveGame(Board):

  Save_file = open('SaveFile.txt', 'w')

  for row in range (BOARDDIMENSION):

     for col in range (BOARDDIMENSION):

         save = Board[row][col]

         Save_file.write(save)

  Save_file.close()
```

Current output: `--D----------D----------D------BBBB--A------m--A---------A---------A-------S-A--------S------PP--S--`

Desired output: Same as above but after every 10 it makes a new line

I have tried using `\n` but got this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\uf709' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Thank you , I hope I complied with the rules , I did search for this issue but didn't find one that matched my needs.

Comment: post the code that produce the error

Comment: Its the same exact code that was recommended below.

Comment: are you sure it is ont that line exactly? also, post the complete error trace

Answer (score 0):

Write a new line at the end of the inner loop.

```
def SaveGame(Board):
    Save_file = open('SaveFile.txt', 'w')
    for row in range (BOARDDIMENSION):
        for col in range (BOARDDIMENSION):
            save = Board[row][col]
            Save_file.write(save)
        Save_file.write('\n')
    Save_file.close()
```

It's unclear what `board` is, is it a list of lists, or a list of strings?. Regardless, a better way to do it would be:

```
def save_game(board):
    with open('SaveFile.txt', 'w') as save_file:
        for row in board:
            save_file.write('{}\n'.format(''.join(row)))
```

Comment: You *do* realize that he also left out the parentheses in `Save_file.close`, don't you?

Comment: Thank you for that it worked , however occasionally when I test the code I get the same error message I got as above , the unicodeEncodeError.

Comment: @zondo: well, no I didn't notice that, but it's not really the problem, is it? But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Padwas: the unicode error must be due to the characters stored in your board. Please show and example of the contents and datatype of the board when you get the exception.